# Filling the slider in a certain amount of time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made HP to the tank, HP is spent when another tank hits the tank, if HP <= 0 then the tank stops for a certain number of seconds (now it's 2 seconds), while the tank is stopped, it should have a HP strip restored in n (now in 2) seconds.

I have already tried to do this using Time.deltaTime, and I managed to adjust the coefficients so that the health is filled in 2 seconds, but what if I want to change the sleep time of the tank? How can the HP be restored in n seconds so that it is smooth? It is worth noting that the values of the slider and HP are [0; 100].

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TankBattleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxHealth;
    public float currentHealth;
    public bool isGround = true;
    public bool isSleep;
    public BattleController battleController;
    public Transform towerTransform;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public WheelCollider[] rightWheelsCol;
    public WheelCollider[] leftWheelsCol;
    public Transform[] rightWheelTrans;
    public Transform[] leftWheelTrans;

    private float _wheelSteer = 100;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (isSleep && currentHealth <= maxHealth)
        {
            battleController.SetHealthBar(currentHealth);
            currentHealth += Time.deltaTime * 50;
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        battleController.SetHealthBar(currentHealth);

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            currentHealth = 0;
            battleController.CheckScore(2, false);
            StartCoroutine(TankSleep());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TankSleep()
    {
        isSleep = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        isSleep = false;
    }
}
```

```
public void CheckScore(int score, bool whom)
{
    if (whom)
    {
        _playerScore += score;
    }
    else
    {
        _botScore += score;
    }
    battleUIManager.scoreText.text = $"{_playerScore} | {_botScore}";
}

public void SetHealthBar(float value)
{
    battleUIManager.healthBar.value = value;
}
```

Comment: I'd advocate against using a Coroutine here and instead use a simple enum-based statemachine to indicate the state. The TakeDamage changes the state from e.g. "alive" to "restore". During restore, you use Time.deltaTime to "recover", using the target duration as both the calculation base for the health percentage and the time until the state changes to "alive" again. No need to rely on unreliable timings in Coroutines. :)

Comment: @MaxPlay can you explain why coroutines are unreliable?

Comment: A coroutine is a statemachine that you push into a black box in Unity. You have little to no control about when exactly it is called. Also, returning a "WaitForSeconds" object makes Unity wait at least this amounts of seconds, but not perfectly. So, if you want it to wait 2 seconds, it can last longer, because of lags, lost focus, too many ticks or just sheer luck. To prevent that, it is better to just use a custom made timer and call it in update. If you check the timer yourself, you can compensate for the 0.x seconds that you are over the timer. Also, it's usually easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way of tweaking a value over a certain time period would be to enclose it in a coroutine.

In your case, this coroutine would restore the health bar from 0 to the maximum value. The code would look like this:

```
// Store the health restoration time in a variable
[SerializeField]
private float healthRestorationTime = 2;

private IEnumerator RestoreHealth()
{
    float timeRemaining = healthRestorationTime;

    while (timeRemaining > 0) 
    {
        // Calculate the current health multiplier. Make sure to clamp it between 0 and 1 
        // (we can only apply a percentage value between 0% and 100%)
        float multiplier = Mathf.Clamp01(1 - timeRemaining / healthRestorationTime);

        // Calculate the current health value
        currentHealth = maxHeath * multiplier;

        // Update the health bar 
        battleController.SetHealthBar(currentHealth);

        // Make sure to decrease the remaining time by the amount of time passed from the last frame
        timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;

        // Wait for the next frame
        yield return null;
    }

    // Make sure to set the health to max at the end of the coroutine
    currentHealth = maxHeath;
}
```

Additionally, if you want the tank to only stop sleeping when the health has been fully restored, you can alter your `TankSleep()` function to look like this:

```
private IEnumerator TankSleep()
{
    isSleep = true;
    yield return StartCoroutine(RestoreHealth());
    isSleep = false;
}
```

Please note that this solution assumes that:

1. The tank sleep time and the helath restoration time are the same.
2. The health restoration coroutine will only be started when the health falls down to 0.

Also, make sure to remove your code from the Update function so that it doesn't try to update the health.

Comment: You can directly do `yield return RestoreHealth();` btw